# CakePHP 2.6: Form validation insisting on the right number of decimals

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cakephp

I recently upgraded my app to CakePHP 2.6 and am now having an issue with a form. The field has a MySQL type of `decimal(9,6)`, and with the new Cake version my form is now insisting that the value not exceed that number of decimal places:

`<?php echo $this->Form->input('lat', array('id' => 'lat', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false)); ?>`

`Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 67.535183 and 67.535182.`

Inspecting the element, I see that FormHelper is applying a `step` of `0.000001` to the fields, based on the database schema.

In the past, MySQL would round the data off and that was fine. Is there a way to get FormHelper to ignore this? Reading the [FormHelper docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html), there's no mention of validating inputs for decimal fields, just turning off validation form-wide. Currently, I can override this by setting the field type to 'text', but that allows non-numeric input.

Comment: schnauss, You should be share of your code then we can  help you.

Comment: what validation error do you get?

Comment: Do you mean a `maxlength` is being applied to the input field or you're getting a validation error?